# how to use devise current_user inside factory_girl factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, factory-bot

I want to use current_user (of devise) inside the factories I create using factory_girl.

My environment contains: Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 2.3.5 / Devise / Cucumber / Pickle / Factory Girl

I've the following models

User:

```
  has_many :for_me, :class_name => "Task", ....details
  has_many :from_me, :class_name => "Task", ....details
```

Task:

```
  belongs_to :assigner, :class_name => "User", ....details
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => "User", ....details
```

I'm testing the following scenario:

```
Given the following users exist
      | email    | password |
      | u1@d.com | 123456   |
      | u1@d.com | 123456   |
And users are confirmed
And I am on the sign in page
And I am logged in as "u1@d.com" with password "123456"
When I fill in "task[description]" with "description 1"
And I press "task_submit"
Then I should see "description 1"
```

The factories I have are:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.first_name          'user_fn'
  f.last_name           'user_ln'
  f.sequence(:username) {|n| "user_#{n}"}
  f.sequence(:email)    {|n| "user_#{n}@domain.com"}
  f.password            '123456'
  f.mobile_number       '0123456798'
end

Factory.define :task do |f|
  f.association :assignee, xxxxxxx
  f.association :assigner, :factory => :user
end
```

My problem is that I want to use current_user of devise instead of the xxxxxxx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't code it directly within the Factory I guess.

Try this:

```
Factory(:task, :assignee => current_user)
```